# Compiler doesn't see generics information when compiling an OSGI 4.2 application using javac

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, osgi, javac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile mavenized OSGi 4.3 bundle with OpenJDK 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911231/how-to-compile-mavenized-osgi-4-3-bundle-with-openjdk-7)

I don't understand what's happening, but the latest OSGI library I'm using has generics information on it for service definitions and the like. When I write source code against this library, my IDE correctly interprets the generics information and lets me write my code.

But when it goes to compile the code with javac, there is a compilation error that "type ServiceFactory does not take parameters". This error doesn't occur using the Eclipse compiler (but the Eclipse compiler in IDEA 11 doesn't seem to like the new JDK 7 language constructs like "new HashMap<>()" so I can't really use it as a replacement).

I read somewhere when I was researching this problem the first time around that there was a problem with the OSGI binary jar in that the class files were compiled for JDK 1.4 binary compatibility and that that was interfering with the generics information being preserved when the compiler loaded the class. I don't remember if that's right because I can't find that web page again when I went to look for it.

So what's the deal here? Why can't javac see the generics information on OSGI 4.x classes so I can use generics in an OSGI application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917093/448551

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Felix and I think it's true for most osgi implementations.  The problem is that Java 7 no longer supporst the compiler flag that those classes were compiled with.  The flag is the -target jsr14. This allows the compiler to produce java byte code that is Java 1.4 compatible, but which also supports the language features of JSR14 ( generics ) that aren't available otherwise until Java 1.5.  OSGi uses this to support it's many users that are bound to the 1.4 platform.  Unfortunately, this compiler flag disappeared with the Java 7 release.

The Felix folks told me that their imminent next version will be compatible with Java 7's compiler.

Here are some references:

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=14

[java compiler's target version "jsr14" with JDK7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058661/java-compilers-target-version-jsr14-with-jdk7-8)

http://markmail.org/search/?q=felix+jsr14+compile#query:felix%20jsr14%20compile+page:1+mid:vgkcr37jumvgpudz+state:results